# automatic id generation which is a primary key

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

in vb.net while entering a new entry i want to assign a record a unique id
like in case of numeric i do  this way

```
Dim ItemID As Integer
KAYAReqConn.Open()
SQLCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ItemID),0) AS ItemID from MstItem", ReqConn)
Dim dr As SqlDataReader

dr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.HasRows Then
    dr.Read()
    ItemID = dr("ItemID") + 1
End If
dr.Close()
```

in this case m using itemid as a unique id
and the format is 1,2,3...
and m finding out the max and assigning to a new record but how to assign if the previous id is of the a00001,a00002,a00003,a00004...so on.
how i do i produce a unique id in this case

Comment: Can't you change your fields of database from varchar to int?

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all ids, access it one by one, break the id and take only integer part, find maximum from them, generate next id and concate it with prefix..store it..

This might be a time consuming process, but I don't find any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better using an auto incrementing int identity field in the database for both these cases.

For the 'a0001', you'd still be better storing this as an integer, and if the 'a0000' is for display, then appending this in your code.  Or possibly having a prefix field to also store the 'a' part - it depends on your requirements.

Comment: how do i write a query since i already have these format in my database and want to find the max value out of this and assign a new value

Comment: @abhi - This must be a new table, if you are just now writing the code to update it? Can somebody look at it? Or if not, can you provide us with the requirements for how your ID should look in the question above?